# How to Stop Asyn Task at onPreExecute?

Tags: android, json, xml

I'm checking for internet connection status in onPreExecute() and If there is no internet connection, it should not execute the doInBackground() and onPostExecute()

```
new getStatus().execute();

private class getStatus extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
```

Comment: Why not check for internet access before executing the `AsyncTask`?

Comment: I can see a point for waiting.  An AsyncTask may not immediately execute if the queue is full, checking it in onPreExecute will catch the case of losing connections between now and then.

Comment: Fair point, but if then that's the case then why not check for internet in `doInBackground()` itself?

Comment: @camelCaseCoder i think it's -flow control- related, at `onPreExecute()` OP can simply Toast "no connection ..." but in case it reached `doInBackground()` that Toast should appear from `onPostExecute()` but how to implement that? assume `doInBackground()` returns array of objects or some json, OP can't control returning `null` for example was because no data in server or the operation failed, or "no connection", right?

Comment: @Yazan yup, makes sense. Excellent point. :)

Comment: Several options. You can show the toast directly from doInBackground, using a handler. You can store a member with the result/error code in your asynctask, read from onPostExecute. Or you can have doInBackground return a custom class containing the retrieved data and/or an error code. Possibilities are endless. Personally I wouldn't put any logic in preExecute that might actually invalidate running the task at all. Besides, Internet connectivity can vanish anytime anyway, including in the middle of your task's execution, so you'd have to handle it from doInBackground anyway?

Answer (score 4):

You set a flag in the AsyncTask in onPreExecute.  Check that flag in the other two functions, and immediately return if the flag is true.

Comment: my 1st thought exactly :), but then i thought about calling `cancel()` at `onPreExecute()` but this is not guaranteed, right?

Comment: I've never tried calling it in onPreExecute, I would expect whether doInBackground gets called to be implementation specific (it depends on where the framework checks).  You could check isCanceled in both functions, I would expect that to work.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
public boolean hasInternetConnection(final Context context) {
    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
    return isConnected;
}
```

put this in onCreate() or anywhere you want to execute task and depending on the result like this:

```
if(hasInternetConnection(YourActivity.this){
   //executeTask
}else{
   //redirect user to Wifi Settings with dialog
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

Since Internet connectivity can disappear at any time, why not simply perform the task and handle the IOException as it happens? If there's no connectivity I guess making a http request or whatever you're doing would fail immediately. You could of course add a check before even trying, but such a check shouldn't *replace* error handling during the network request.

I would probably put all logic in doInBackground. If I add a check for connectivity first, I would handle it the same way as any network exceptions occurring during the actual request.
As for the actual error handling, you could store an error code as a member  in your asynctask, you could have the asynctask work on a custom class containing both data and error code, or you could even have doInBackground return null in case of error and handle the errors directly from doInBackground.